# On the Markov Chain Theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

For an ergodic Markov chain with the transition probability matrix $P$, the Markov chain theorem stats that the limiting probabilities $\pi_{j}$ (i.e. the long-run proportions) can be computed by the linear system

$$\pi_{j}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\pi_{i}P_{ij}$$ and $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\pi_{i}=1$$
This means that $limit_{n\rightarrow\infty}P^{n}$ exist and can be found by solving the above linear system.

If the entries of the transition probability matrix depend on $n$ (we denote this matrix by $P^{[n]}$), then if $limit_{n\rightarrow\infty}P^{[n]}=P$, how to compute the corresponding limiting probabilites? Is there a result similar to the ergodic Markov chain theorem? In other words, how to compute $limit_{n\rightarrow\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}P^{[k]}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Haven’t you just showed us how? You have a linear system in sufficiently many variables, you can solve it